# How to prevent to add new attributes to images those which are in browser visible area

Tags: jquery

i have many images showing in my page which comes one after one. when we run page then 4 or 5 images i can see at time and when scroll down then next few images gets visible. i iterate in images collection inside a specific div and add some attribute to those images in a specific div by jquery like this way

```
 $(".diagnostic_picture img").each(function () {
                var img = $(this);
                img.attr("class", "lazy");
                img.attr("data-original", img.attr("src"));
                img.attr("src", "images/grey.gif");
 });
```

now i want to add these new attribute to those images which are not invisible when page load first time.

so i trying to detect images are in viewport or not....if not then i would add these new attribute.
here is code

```
 $(".diagnostic_picture img").each(function () {
            if ($(this).offset().top > $(window).scrollTop() && $(this).offset().top < $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) {
                var img = $(this);
                img.attr("class", "lazy");
                img.attr("data-original", img.attr("src"));
                img.attr("src", "images/grey.gif");
            }
        });
```

but it is not working....the new attribute like class,data-original etc are getting added to all images which i do not want. so my requirement is that i would add some attribute to those images in my page which are not in view port initially until anyone scroll down. so what i need to change in my code.

### I have solved the issue this way

```
$(".diagnostic_picture img").each(function () {
                var img = $(this);
                var pageHeight = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
                if (img.offset().top > pageHeight) 
                {
                    img.attr("class", "lazy");
                    img.attr("data-original", img.attr("src"));
                    img.attr("src", "images/grey.gif");
                }
 });
```

This way i checked the images are in viewport or not

```
var img = $(this);
var pageHeight = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
if (img.offset().top > pageHeight) 
{
    // if images are in viewport then i will do something
}
```

anyway thanks for having look at my question.

Comment: To how many images do you want to apply the attributes? I am sure I can change your selector to do that.

Comment: are you running both selectors you stated above?... if so of course you will have all images with the attribute.. the first "each" is for all images. without the if condition. have you tried debugging it? do you see that the if condition works? and its actually blocking some of the elements?

Comment: my requirement is i will add attribute to those images which are not in viewport initially until scroll down the page.

Comment: i solved my prob....just have a look. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show only the first 4 images in `diagnostic_picture`, you could select only those by:

```
$(".diagnostic_picture img:lt(5)")
```

Comment: my requirement is i will add attribute to those images which are not in viewport initially until scroll down the page.

Comment: `:lt` stands for lesser than. Out of all images it will select those that are less than 5 in the array.